# got error again when I install rpy2 (compiled by llvm in brew)

Tags: llvm-clang, rpy2

When I ran 'pip install rpy2', it reported error:

> clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'

I installed llvm with brew since it supports the option. But I have to link brew's llvm (clang-5.0) to clang command. Then I ran 'pip install rpy2', now I got new error. How do I fix it?

```
ld: library not found for -lomp
    clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command '/usr/local/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There an open issue on the rpy2 tracker with a similar error message, and an active discussion where some are reporting success compiling rpy2 after the combination of dev tools provided by Apple and requirements to compile the latest R release became incompatible:
https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/403/cannot-pip-install-rpy2-with-latest-r-340